# Get row number with Google spreadsheet query language

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to get the row number of the data I need with query language, i.g: select A,ROW_NUMBER() where (B=1).

But it seems the query language doesn't provide function like: ROW_NUMBER()?

How do I do that, other than query the whole column and count it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can include a row number in a `query()` by using an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

```
=arrayformula( query({A2:B, row(A2:B)}, "select Col1, Col3 where Col2 = 1", 0) )
```

In the query statement, `Col1` is column `A`, `Col2` is column `B`, and `Col3` is the "virtual" column that contains row numbers. These "ColX" type column references need to be used whenever the data is not a spreadsheet range or a reference, but a computed array such as an `arrayformula()` result or an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).

The `arrayformula()` wrapper is required here to evaluate the `row()` function over a range of cells rather than just the top left cell.

Comment: When you say "add a column" do you mean manually in the sheet, or only programmatically as shown in your example?   Is this for the Google Visualization API or Google Sheets API?

Comment: This is a Google Sheets spreadsheet formula that includes the built-in `query()` function, which uses the [GViz query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax).

Answer (score 10):

Note that when the spreadsheet is in a locale that uses commas as decimal separators, you will need to change the comma in the { array expression } to a backslash `\` and the rest of the commas to semicolons `;` like this:

```
=arrayformula( query({A2:B \ row(A2:B)}; "select Col1, Col3 where Col2 = 1"; 0) )
```

From [the array help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276):

> Note: For countries that use commas as decimal separators (for example
> €1,00), commas would be replaced by backslashes (`\`) when creating
> arrays.

To set the spreadsheet locale, choose **File > Spreadsheet settings**.